# Why does my Expo-built React Native app crash after splash screen with no error messages?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, publish, expo-build

After building the react native expo app on expo dev, I installed it, on opening the app, it crashed after loading the splash screen.
I am not getting anything errors from the console or popup errors.
this is my package.json ...

```
{
  "name": "hagmus",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/kurale": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/quicksand": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/raleway": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "expo": "^48.0.17",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "9.6.11",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "obfuscator-io-metro-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-share": "^8.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.11",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "^6.26.0",
    "babylon": "^6.18.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Please someone should help me.

I updated all the dependencies on package.json and expo-cli but it still keeps crashing after the splash screen

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're using expo and attempting to use the react native clipboard package. Expo has it's own clipboard, expo-clipboard. So, if you're implementing something with react-native-clipboard, it may be crashing when ios is bundling.